ApolloError: Failed to parse URL from /graphql
I have faced following issue during running NextJS project.
This is error screenshot.
Above image is just my error that I have faced over.
I found solution here, but I didn't solve it yet.
I have tried to re-install npm, but I didn't solve it.
I am expecting solution.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include code, data and error messages as text, not images.
